# Post to multiple user walls in facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

So I have been going through the facebook developer documentation and I have managed to get to a point where the user clicks the facebook login button and gives me publish permissions. Then my function will post something to their wall.

My question: Is their a way for my facebook app to post to the walls of all the users who have given my app publish permissions, using either the javascript sdk or the php sdk.

My current code:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
        FB.login(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        },{scope: 'publish_actions'});
    } else {
        FB.login(function(response) {
           console.log(response);
        },{scope: 'publish_actions'});
    };
});

function postAPI() {
    var body = 'We are testing the ability of posting on users behalf.';
    FB.api('/me/feed','post',{message:body},function(response){
        if (!response || response.error) {
            alert('Error occurred');
        } else {
            console.log('Post ID: ' + response.id);
        };
    });
};
```

Comment: Server-side you could do that, if you get long-term access tokens (60 days) for them and store those. But I think it might be considered spammy quite quickly - and also actually violate Platform Policies, because you are not supposed to post content that the user did not in one way or another type in themselves. Publishing updates on a fan page and having people like it so that those posts show up in their feed is the preferred way to go if you just want to reach people with your news. Or, if it's all individual content about something the user did, then use Open Graph actions instead.

Comment: Thank you @CBroe a fan page would probably be much easier.